# getting data from Arrays - PHP

Tags: php

Okay, I'm kinda stuck on really silly problem, but still can't figure out.

I'm having an array from database with `mysql_fetch_array`. So far I have only 1 record in the table and after print_r(....) I have this:

```
Array (
   [0] => 1 
   [customer_id] => 1 
   [1] => Test Client 
   [customer_name] => Test Client 
   [2] => 
   [customer_image] => 
   [3] => Test Address 
   [customer_address] => Test Address 
   [4] => 2272723 
   [customer_phone] => 2272723
)
```

I'm trying to make a `foreach() {...}` from where I'll get customer_id and customer_name

and somehow I can't make correct foreach to get them and I'm getting some hilarious results...

any ideas?

=================

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers";
$result_set = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);
$records = mysql_fetch_array($result_set);

function generateSelect($recordName, $label, $default) {
        $records = parent::selectTableRecord($recordName);
      $html = "<label for=\"".$recordName."\">". $label ."</label>";
      $html .= "<select name=\"". $recordName ."\" id=\"". $recordName ."\">";
      $html .= "<option value=\"\">". $default ."</option>";
          while ($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
            $html .= "<option value=\"".$record['customer_id']."\">".$record['customer_name']."</option>";
          }
      $html .= "</select>";
      return $html; 
    }
```

and somewhere on other page I'm echoing this function:

```
<?php echo Project::generateSelect('customer', 'client', '--'); ?>
```

here's what I have

Comment: can you show your result here?

Comment: what is the query? What is the foreach loop code? use mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array.

Comment: I can't show you the result because it's in html SELECT form, but I can say that I'm getting displayed not what it's indended to be..

I could use WHILE and it would work fine, but am thinking to hold on to foreach probably, looks nicer and cleaner.. so any ideas how to optimize it?

Comment: @Leonardo - I added what I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way would be to use this code :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer");
while($posts = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $posts['customer_name'];
}
```

**Updated answer to reflect the exact vars used in the question**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers";
$result_set = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);
while($records = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)){
   echo $records['customer_name'];
}
```

now #customer_name can be replaced by ANY field name you have in that table to get that data.

and if you wanted to use foreach to have $i as a number to keep track of the number of results, then you can create `$i = 0;` outside the `while()` and at the end before closing it, just add `$i++`.

Comment: yeah, thanks for advice.. I wanted to play with foreach, but as I can see I have to code more to use foreach.. I did what you wrote here.. and now I have this stupid Resource id #101  <-- what's that?

Comment: if I am not mistaking you echoed an array or something, because echoing arrays usually returns a resource ID #something error, can you paste the entire code you have here including your mysql query.

Comment: I added it.. some lines are extra, but pay attention...

Comment: updated the answer, tell me if it works!

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach ($data as $id => $val)
{
    if ($id == 'customer_id')
       echo $val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// $resultSet = mysql_query(...);
for ($data = array(); $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultSet); $data[] = $row);
$customerId = $data['customer_id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

That function only returns one row at a time (the *next* row). Use a while loop , not a foreach loop (from [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
}
```

Comment: yeah probably could use while, but still thinking to correct my foreach...

Answer (score 1):

you can use mysql_fetch_assoc instead if array then

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
{
if ($key=='customer_id')
    echo $val;
if ($key=='customer_name')
    echo $val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
   if($key == "customer_id")
       // do smth
```

What kind of "hilarious results?"
If by that you mean that you have two keys for the same value (`array[0] === array['customer_id']`),that can be fixed. One way is to get rid of the numeric indexes by casting the array to an object :

```
foreach((object)$data as $key => $value)
    // do smth
```

Comment: I can't show you the result because it's in html SELECT form, but I can say that I'm getting displayed not what it's indended to be..

I could use WHILE and it would work fine, but am thinking to hold on to foreach probably, looks nicer and cleaner.. so any ideas how to optimize it?

(object) <-- just directly write object?